# i have include html form element with php but that does not post

Tags: php, post

hi i use a form and i add  a few textarea my form with php. But i click submit buton it does not post. Why? is there any problem?

```
 <form onsubmit="return form_kontrol()" name="form1" class="block-content form" id="simple_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
```

```js
<div id="kodlar">
                 
< ? php 
     $i=1;
     mysql_select_db($database_verisi_tabanisi, $verisi_tabanisi);
    $query_sipsa = "SELECT * FROM sifreler where kayit_id=".$_GET['id'];
    $sipsa = mysql_query($query_sipsa, $verisi_tabanisi) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_sipsa = mysql_fetch_array($sipsa);
    $totalRows_sipsa=mysql_num_rows($sipsa);
do{
echo "<p style=\"display:inline;\" id=\"p".$i."\">
                  <label for=\"sifre\">Kod  ".$i.":</label>
     <textarea disabled name=\"kod".$i."\" id=\"kod".$i."\"  cols=\"70\" rows=\"3\" style=\"margin-left:10px;\">".$row_sipsa['sifre']."</textarea>
<a href=\"?sil=".$row_sipsa['id']."&id=".$_GET['id']."\" title=\"Sil\" class=\"with-tip ask\"><img src=\"images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"></a>
<p>";
$i++;
} while($row_sipsa = mysql_fetch_array($sipsa));


? >
            </div>
```

this is php code and everything is normal.

```
             <table width="461px"> 
            <tr>  <td width="35%"><label for="kullanici">İsim Soyisim:</label></td>
              <td width="65%"><input name="isim" type="text" id="isim" class="full-width" style="width:300px;" value="<?php echo $row_sipsa['isim_soyisim'];?>"></td>
              </tr>
              </table>

              <br>  <br>

              <table width="461px"> 
            <tr>  <td width="35%"><label for="sifre">Telefon:</label></td>
              <td width="65%"><input name="tel" type="text" id="tel"  class="full-width" style="width:300px;" value="<?php echo $row_sipsa['telefon'];?>"></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: form post input text value but dont post textarea write with php. the all form elements is between form tags.

Comment: please post the JavaScript function `form_kontrol()` as well

Answer (score 0):

Disabled form element won't post to other page.

If you want make textarea disabled the  you have below options:

1. Make them readonly by adding the readonly property to the element.
2. disable them in CSS/JavaScript. Color it like it's disabled, and
   don't allow editing with JavaScript
3. Leave it disabled, and remove the disabled on submit.

Choose anyone. :-)